# Regex query in solr

Tags: regex, solr

I'm trying to make a regex query in solr using lookahead to match terms in any order. It's not working.

I'm doing the following query:

```
q=(itemKeyword:/(?=.*REDE).*(?=.*ENLACE).*/)
```

To get the document containing:

> "INTERFACE GERENCIAMENTO RADIO ENLACE - APLICACAO: MICROONDAS, TIPO ACESSO: REMOTO TELEACIONAMENTO, ARMAZENAMENTO DADOS: HD, CANAL SERVICO: N/A, MONITOR: N/A, FUNCAO: GERENCIAMENTO DE REDE"

Comment: Try `itemKeyword:/.*REDE.*&.*ENLACE.*/`

Comment: Thank you. I worked like a charm.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the regular full text search feature in Solr to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `&` operator:

```
itemKeyword:/.*REDE.*&.*ENLACE.*/
```

The pattern matches a string that contains both `REDE` and `ENLACE`.